# Web scraping with BeautifulSoup .find() always returns None

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Relevant part of the DOM:
[Screenshot of the DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQsX8.png)

This is the code I wrote:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://www.cheapflights.com.sg/flight-search/SIN-KUL/2022-06-04?sort=bestflight_a&attempt=3&lastms=1653844067064'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
flight = soup.find('div', class_= 'resultWrapper')
print(flight)
```

The result that I get whenever print(flight) is executed is always None. I have tried changing to div tags with different class names but it still always returns None.
The soup seems to be fine though because when I execute print(soup) it returns a text version of the DOM so the problem seems to be with the next line

Any suggestions on how I can get something other than None? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the User-Agent. If I try to curl the page without changing the default User-Agent, it'll return [this](https://www.cheapflights.com.sg/help/bots.html) page.

Change your code like this, to avoid that your program gets detected:

```py
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) ..."
}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
```